# Email subject line is all the information I want to convey. How to instruct the sender (in the subject line itself) to not open the email body?

Tags: abbreviations, phrase-requests, email, acronyms

I want to write an email (to my boss) in which all the information is conveyed in the subject line itself:

- "Won't be doing the Strawberry Project"
- "Your work is in process"
- "Come quick. Party happening"

In such cases, I want to instruct the reader not to open the mail body. Is there an email abbreviation to put in the subject line to instruct the reader to do so?

Something like NNO (No Need to Open).

Is there some short form or abbreviation to do this?

Comment: End the subject with "This mail has no body" or begin it with "No message-body."

Comment: This question is not about the English language *per se*.

Comment: @Kris If we don’t support questions like this, why is there an `email` tag ?

Comment: @k1eran Just click on the tag button "email" under the question above. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris Can you explain why you think this question isn't about English? To me it doesn't look any different than a single word request, except OP wants an abbreviation.

Comment: @Laurel A question about abbreviations is when what needs abbreviated is spelled out exactly and has a standard abbreviation. Not about "how can I phrase it?"

Comment: @Laurel Also, the wording of your comment is not quite in line with a place like ELU.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to English Language and Usage.

Comment: In fairness, pretty much the only question tagged "email" that hasn't been closed is asking for a replacement for "As indicated in the attachment", so this question could easily be viewed as in that spirit.

Answer (score 4):

Write `(eom)` or  `<eom>`at the end of the e-mail subject.

> **EOM (end-of-message)**.
>
> EOM stands for "end of message."
>
> People who exchange a great deal of e-mail sometimes write a very short message in the subject line of an e-mail note and conclude it with: (EOM). This is a little faster to send and saves the receiver from having to take the time to open the note, since the entire message is visible in the subject line. The "(EOM)" is a signal that the message is wholly contained in the subject line.
>
> — [techtarget.com](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/EOM-end-of-message)

Longer explanations at [lifehacker.com](https://lifehacker.com/5028808/how-eom-makes-your-email-more-efficient) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_message).

Personally I regularly see this used.

Comment: Are the down-votes because the answer is wrong, or because we should not answer this type of question, or both ?

Comment: +1 EOM is a commonly used in email to express exactly this, and this is a good answer to the question.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I would have given, but you need to make sure everybody understands it and respects it.   I have had the experience of sending an email with a subject like “I have finished XYZ and checked it in <EOM>”, and had people reply, adding a body to the message, and leaving the subject as “Re: I have finished XYZ and checked it in <EOM>”.   So it becomes useless.